# How does -Infinity actually work?

Tags: javascript

```
    STACKOVERFLOW = [];
    turkeycheck = Math.max.apply(null, STACKOVERFLOW);
    if(!turkeycheck){
         // See Below
    }

console.log(turkeycheck);
console.log(turkeycheck.length);
```

Can also be visible here: http://jsfiddle.net/L4zgfcmz/5/

Just curious why `(!turkey)` doesn't get catched but using `turkeycheck.length` shows it's undefined? If it's undefined doesn't that mean it's false?

Also, if `turkey` is console logging `-Infinity`, shouldn't the length of `turkeycheck` become 11?

I'm just confused as why the `turkey` is being set to '-Infinity', but then becomes `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-Infinity` is a numeric value. Numeric values do not have a `.length` property, so attempting to read from it will return `undefined`. The value held in your `turkeycheck` variable itself remains unchanged, and if you attempt to log its value after attempting to log its length, you'll still be shown the value `-Infinity`.

```
var n = 1;
console.log(n.length); // undefined
console.log(n);        // 1
```

Comment: Oh... so `-Infinity` is actually a numerical value? That seems odd, lol. Thought it was a damn string. My bad. I get it now.
Edit: With that said, is there a shorthand method to check for `-Infinity`, like  `!`?

Comment: @NiCkNewman it's a part of the IEEE754 standard, including `-0`, `+0` and `NaN`

Comment: @NiCkNewman yep. If it were a string your console would be displaying quotation marks (`"-Infinity"` instead of `-Infinity`).